# Is it badly viewed to have company funded research during one's thesis when applying for their first postdoc

Tags: postdocs, funding, biology

I have a friend that might be doing an academic (not industrial) thesis in a biology related topic where one of the projects would be funded by a company that sells a product that will be tested in the research. I have the impression that research that's funded by a company tends to be regarded as not being trustworthy as there is the incentive of the company.

I am concerned whether this could affect the review of their CV when applying for postdoc positions when compared to other students that might have only done purely academic research.

Comment: There is a very similar question in the link ( Funding of research by commercial companies, what is the sentiment in the USA?: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/19783/182553 ) in the related section of this page that I do not really recall seeing in the suggestions when writing the question (is the related section different than the initial suggestions?). I also do not recall seeing it in a site specific google search.

Comment: Once upon a time companies like GE, IBM, and Bell Labs funded lots of research. Nobody thought twice about it, but it was in all cases quite clear that it was fundamental research.

Comment: I am weighing in the pros and the cons especially that they have not yet started their thesis and might have time to change project if needed (I am not sure). According to https://www.sydney.edu.au/news-opinion/news/2019/10/03/when-big-companies-fund-academic-research-the-truth-often-comes.html it seems to say companies might try to get academic researchers under an agenda that benefits them (so the research could be true but maybe implicitly or explicitly constrained/incomplete) and that a paper that does not favor them might not be allowed to publish (which is maybe a separate question).

Answer (score 3):

I think that concern is more for "research" (yes, in quotes) by company employees who have a conflict of interest in publishing results. The tobacco companies and the fossil fuel industries are famous for this.

But an external researcher has no such conflict as the funding is for the research not for their careers. Such people can be honest in what they say and so there need be no assumption that it might be tainted.

It could be different, if the researcher were promised additional things after completion of the research provided it turns out the "right way" (hint wink hint). Presumably the supervisor of the student is an academic with academic concerns paramount.

Comment: Thank you I did not know about the distinction internal (within company)/external (outside of company within university) when considering company funded research.Your answer makes sense to me thank you again.

Comment: _But an external researcher has no such conflict as the funding is for the research not for their careers._ - I think it depends on the situation.  If a company is giving you financial incentives to do research, this can easily create conflicts of interest.